# How to make sure that inputs stay filled when a popup comes up (PHP/HTML)

Tags: php, html

So when you press "Register" this popup comes up

```
<div class='warn-splash-bg'>
    <div class='warn-splash'>
        <span class='fa-stack fa-4x' style='color: #C7B017; margin-top: 10px;'>
            <i class='fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x'></i>
            <i class='fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-stack-1x'></i>
        </span>
        <h2 class='warn-main basic-font'>Warning:</h2>
        <p class='warn-desc basic-font'>By joining this site you agree to the Terms Of Service</p>
        <input type='submit' value='Agree' class='tos-agree-btn' name='agree-tos' />
        <input type='button' value='Decline' class='tos-decline-btn' />
    </div>
</div>
```

For some reason when this popup comes up, it clears the other inputs on the page that you need to fill in to create an account. Thus, making it so it doesn't work.

```
//php
if ($agree) {
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
   $_SESSION['hash'] = $encrypt;
   $data1 = "INSERT INTO users 
                    (username, password, email, ip, datecreated) 
             VALUES (:username, :password, :email, :ip, :datecreated)";
    $data2 = $handler->prepare($data1);
    $data2->execute(array(':username' => $username, 
                          ':password' => $encrypt, 
                          ':email' => $email, 
                          ':ip' => $ip, 
                          ':datecreated' => $date)
                   );
    $giveEmeralds = $handler->query("UPDATE users SET emeralds=5 WHERE username='$username'");
    header("Location: ../");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: The popup has a SUBMIT button in it, but who knows what form it is going to submit. I would suppose from your question, it is not the form on the main page.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a form where you have those inputs you mention. You can add an javascript event to your submit that will submit that form:

```
<input type='submit' value='Agree' class='tos-agree-btn' name='agree-tos' onclick='document.getElementById("yourFormId").submit(); return false;' />
```